# Trying to pass a string stored in a pandas structure to a method

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pandas

So I have data stored in a panda structure. And One of the columns of my data is comprised of strings.

1 by 1, I want to be able to go through the panda structure pulling that string out. Sending it to a method that cleans it up and then store it back.

```
data = pd.read_csv('ml_dataset_train1.csv', )
data.dropna(how="all", inplace=True)

text = data.loc[data['Id']>=0,['Interview']]

trainDataPercent = 0.75

train_data = text[0:int(trainDataPercent*len(text))]
test_data = text[int(trainDataPercent*len(text)):len(text)]

texts = train_data

for i in range(0, len(texts)):
    texts.iat[i, 0] = cd.review_to_words(texts.iat[i, 0])
```

This gives me the error that my method is expecting a string. What is even more strange, is that when I check the type of `texts.iat[1, 0]`, I get "class 'str'".

So why is my method not accepting it?

Comment: Maybe some other index has something other than `str` , not the first index? Did you try adding a condition inside the `for` loop - `if isinstance(texts.iat[i,0]), str):` ?

Comment: In that column they are all strings. Or maybe they aren't depending how panda dealt with it. 

But they are sequences of characters coming from text in a csv file.

Comment: Or you can also print the `i` and check exactly which `i` you got error for and then check that row in the csv. Maybe if you are unable to find any issue in that row, you can add it here, we can try checking